# Is it possible by hovering over the tab area to toggle the tab bar visibility in Chrome with CSS logic?

Tags: firefox

I know that (via `userChrome.css` ﬁle) the tab bar can be hidden and then be made visible by hovering over its area but as soon as the mouse leaves the tab area, it goes back to hiding.

So with CSS logic, is it possible by hovering over the tab area to toggle the tab bar visibility?

For example, if the tab bar is currently visible, hovering over it toggles visibility to off and it remains off when the mouse leaves the tab area.

I really need a way to toggle its visibility on/off at will.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior when in full screen mode.

Testing in both Firefox and Edge, the tab, title, and address bars are hidden when you press F11 and go full screen. Moving your mouse to the top of the screen reveals the hidden upper UI elements.

Whether this works in windowed mode will depend on whether the browser has included this into the code.